# Invoking p:dataExporter in p:contextMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, contextmenu, data-export

I want to use dataExporter as onclick action in my right-click contextMenu.
Sadly, I have no idea how to manage this :(

dataExporter(simple export table date to XLS) and contextMenu are binded to the same dataTable.

here's the code:

```
<p:contextMenu for = "tableForm">
    <p:menuitem value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:contextMenu>

<p:commandLink ajax="false" width="24">
    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/Excel-icon.png" />
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="dataTable"
        fileName="daneCentrumDataTable" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: how about trying to use an onclick on the menuitem in the contextmenu and then doing a 'click' on the commandLink?

Comment: Could you show me how to perform 'click' one the commandLink?

Comment: No, sorry  lots of examples in stackoverflow, google etc.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Kukeltje idea something like this:

```
<p:contextMenu for="dataTable">
    <p:menuitem value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    <p:menuitem value="Export" onclick="$('#export').click()" />
</p:contextMenu>

<div style="display: none;">
    <p:commandLink id="export" ajax="false" width="24">
       <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="dataTable" fileName="daneCentrumDataTable" />
   </p:commandLink>
</div>
```

P.S.: My `h:form` has `prependId="false"`

Comment: Works great! Thank you Miguel! I will use it many times today, it was really valuable help.